# For skew-symmetric $U$, prove that $U(1-U^\dagger U)^{-1}$ is, too

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $U$ be a complex skew-symmetric matrix ($U = -U^\mathsf{T}$, where $U^\mathsf{T}$ means the transpose of $U$). I want to show that $U(1 - U^\dagger U)^{-1}$ is also skew-symmetric. Here $U^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose (Hermitian conjugate) of $U$.

I have numerically tested this statement, and it seems to be true as long as $1 - U^\dagger U$ is invertible. I attempted to use the eigen-decomposition of $U^\dagger U$ to prove it, but it does not seem to help much.

Comment: By "skew-symmetric", do you mean that $U = U^\dagger$ or $U = U^\top$?

Comment: I mean $U = -U^\mathsf{T}$, following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M = U\left(I - U^{\dagger}U\right)^{-1}$ since $U^{\dagger} = -\overline{U}$, then

$$M = U\left(I + \overline U U\right)^{-1}$$ and

\begin{align}
M^\intercal &= \left(I + U\overline U\right)^{-1}U^{\intercal}\\
&= -\left(I + U\overline U\right)^{-1}U\\
&= -\left(I + U\overline U\right)^{-1}U\left(I + \overline U U\right)\left(I + \overline U U\right)^{-1}\\
&= -\left(I + U\overline U\right)^{-1}\left(U + U\overline U U\right)\left(I + \overline U U\right)^{-1}\\
&= -\left(I + U\overline U\right)^{-1}\left(I + U\overline U \right)U\left(I + \overline U U\right)^{-1}\\
&= -U\left(I + \overline U U\right)^{-1} = -M
\end{align}

Comment: Why should the matrices $(I + \bar U U )^{-1}$ and $U$ commute?

Comment: I did not use that they commute

Comment: I misread the last line of equations, my mistake

Comment: Yes I edit the answer and include all steps

Comment: I had a mistake after all: I mixed the order of $U^\dagger$ and $U$. Recalculation confirms your result.

Comment: Ah yes I was commenting on that.